# Larger than life

Tags: riddle

What is larger than life,

But smaller than existence?

What is longer than a year,

But shorter than a microsecond?

What is more than a metre,

But less than a centimetre?

What is bigger than sixty,

But smaller than thirteen?

Note/Hint:

> There are an infinite number of correct solutions, if you have the right idea. The accepted answer will have any word that satisfies the conditions set out above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go by

> Number of letters in each word and use those as the limits

An answer is

> Seventy

Comment: Much quicker than I thought, great job.